# Haskell Hash table

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a smallish haskell app that will translate a few key phrases from english to french.

First, i have a list of ordered pairs of strings that represent and english word/phrase followed by the french translations:

```
icards = [("the", "le"),("savage", "violent"),("work", "travail"),
("wild", "sauvage"),("chance", "occasion"),("than a", "qu'un")...]
```

next i have a new data:

```
data Entry = Entry {wrd, def :: String, len :: Int, phr :: Bool}
deriving Show
```

then i use the icards to populate a list of Entrys:

```
entries :: [Entry]
entries = map (\(x, y) -> Entry x y (length x) (' ' `elem` x)) icards
```

for simplicity, i create a new type that will be [Entry] called Run.

Now, i want to create a hash table based on the number of characters in the english word.  This will be used later to speed up searchings.  So i want to create a function called runs:

```
runs :: [Run]
runs = --This will run through the entries and return a new [Entry] that has all of the
         words of the same length grouped together.
```

I also have:

```
maxl = maximum [len e | e <- entries]
```

Comment: So are you asking for a solution in which `data Entry = Entry {wrd, def :: String, len :: Int, phr :: Bool} | [Entry]` ?

Comment: I dont understand that... but no, not so much a solutions, as a recommended path.  I have looked at filter, and feel like i need to use that.  But i just cant figure out how to do a "for" loop, when i can loop through the maxl index and populate a list on that.

Comment: Well what i mean is how are you planning on making an Entry that is a group of entries? I was proposing making Entry an algebraic data type that ranges over Entry and [Entry]

Comment: I don't understand the goal - is this a learning exercise?  Is there a good reason you aren't using the hash tables from `hashtables` or hashmap from the `unordered-containers` package?

Comment: it is a learning exercise... and only the second haskell app i have ever tried to tackle.  I dont want to go past data.list and data.functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`groupBy` and `sortBy` are both in `Data.List`.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function -- for `on`
runs :: [Run]
runs = f 0 $ groupBy ((==) `on` len) $ sortBy (compare `on` len) entries
  where f _                              []           =      []
        f i (r @ (Entry {len = l} : _) : rs) | i == l = r  : f (i + 1) rs
        f i                              rs           = [] : f (i + 1) rs
```

Personally, I would use a Map instead

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
runs :: M.Map String Entry
runs = M.fromList $ map (\entry -> (wrd entry, entry)) entries
```

and lookup directly by English word instead of a two step length-of-English-word and then English-word process.

Comment: `groupBy` and `sortBy` take `(a -> a -> Bool)` and `(a -> a -> Ordering)` respectively. I fixed that :)

Comment: This looks good, one thing i was hoping for.  was to have it 0 indexed, for simplicity.  Meaning runs!!0 = [[]], runs!!1 = [[--List of 1 char]] etc.

Answer (score 9):

It just so happens that Hackage has a [hashmap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap) package! I'm going to create a small data type based on that HashMap, which I will call a MultiMap. This is a typical trick: it's just a hash map of linked lists. I'm not sure what the correct name for MultiMap actually is.

```
import qualified Data.HashMap as HM
import Data.Hashable

import Prelude hiding (lookup)

type MultiMap k v = HM.Map k [v]

insert :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => k -> a -> MultiMap k a -> MultiMap k a
insert k v = HM.insertWith (++) k [v]

lookup :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => k -> MultiMap k a -> [a]
lookup k m = case HM.lookup k m of
  Nothing -> []
  Just xs -> xs

empty :: MultiMap k a
empty = HM.empty

fromList :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => [(k,v)] -> MultiMap k v
fromList = foldr (uncurry insert) empty
```

I mimicked only the essentials of a Map: insert, lookup, empty, and fromList. Now it is quite easy to turn `entries` into a `MutliMap`:

```
data Entry = Entry {wrd, def :: String, len :: Int, phr :: Bool}
           deriving (Show)

icards = [("the", "le"),("savage", "violent"),("work", "travail"),
          ("wild", "sauvage"),("chance", "occasion"),("than a", "qu'un")]

entries :: [Entry]
entries = map (\(x, y) -> Entry x y (length x) (' ' `elem` x)) icards

fromEntryList :: [Entry] -> MutiMap Int Entry
fromEntryList es = fromList $ map (\e -> (len e, e)) es
```

Loading that up into ghci, we can now lookup a list of entries with a given length:

```
ghci> let m = fromEntryList entries
ghci> lookup 3 m
[Entry {wrd = "the", def = "le", len = 3, phr = False}]
ghci> lookup 4 m
[Entry {wrd = "work", def = "travail", len = 4, phr = False},
 Entry {wrd = "wild", def = "sauvage", len = 4, phr = False}]
```

(Note that this `lookup` is not the one defined in Prelude.) You could similarly use the English word as a key.

```
-- import Data.List (find) -- up with other imports

fromEntryList' :: [Entry] -> MultiMap String Entry
fromEntryList' es = fromList $ map (\e -> (wrd e, e)) es

eLookup :: String -> MultiMap String Entry -> Maybe Entry
eLookup str m = case lookup str m of
  [] -> Nothing
  xs -> find (\e -> wrd e == str) xs
```

Testing...

```
ghci> let m = fromEntryList' entries
ghci> eLookup "the" m
Just (Entry {wrd = "the", def = "le", len = 3, phr = False})
ghci> eLookup "foo" m
Nothing
```

Notice how in `eLookup` we first perform the Map lookup in order to determine if anything has been placed in that slot. Since we are using a hash set, we need to remember that two different Strings might have the same hash code. So in the event that the slot is not empty, we perform a `find` on the linked list there to see if any of the entries there actually match the correct English word. If you are interested in performance, you should consider using `Data.Text` instead of `String`.

Comment: Really wow... a really great answer.  But i feel like i cant use much of it.  This is a learning exercise so i cant use these complex imports.  But thank you very much